# Update scope value after dynamically update textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

in AngularJS I have scenario that the user selects a value from a grid in a popup and selected value is displayed in textbox in container page. After the user select a value, popup raises an event which is captured in container page. Now I can set the value of textbox using `.val()` but how do I update Model?

```
$scope.$on('rowSelectedInPopup', function (event: ng.IAngularEvent, ...data) {
    if (elementId === data[1].toString()) {
        $(elementId).val(data[0].toString());
        $(elementId + "_inlinelbl").html(data[0].toString());
    }
});
```

Here is my textbox and label html:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="ServiceManagerglookup" ng-model="Model.Person2.Name" />
<label id="ServiceManagerglookup_inlinelbl" ng-model="Model.Person2.Name">ABC</label>
```

Please note that textbox can bound with any arbitrary field in scope e.g. Model.AVC.XYZ.LMN

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood but; Remember two way binding is one of the key features in Angular - instead of changing the view you should simply change the model and the data will be updated automatically. So through your controller simply set `$scope.Model.Person2.Name = html(data[0].toString())`. When you have done that the input element with `ng-model="Model.Person2.Name"` will simply be updated.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The problem is that Model.Person2.Name is also dynamic because the control can be used in different places and bound to different fields. So I have to do something like scope["Model"]["Person2"]["Name"] which can change with every screen. So i think the right question is "how can I update a value in scope if I have a string like Model.Person2.Name or Model.ABC.XYZ.PQR"

Comment: I see - I can't think of any other solution besides simply splitting said string; `var array = string.split('.')` and then doing `$scope.array[0].array[1].array[2].array[3] = html(data[0].toString())` Not exactly a nice solution, but a solution nonetheless

Comment: this will fix only one case. what if string is Model.ABC then I will need $scope.array[0].array[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides changing the value you also need to inform Angular that a value changed using

`$(elementId).trigger('input');`

Like this

```
$scope.$on('rowSelectedInPopup', function (event: ng.IAngularEvent, ...data) {
    if (elementId === data[1].toString()) {
        $(elementId).val(data[0].toString());
        $(elementId + "_inlinelbl").html(data[0].toString());
        $(elementId).trigger('input');
    }
});
```

Triggering of this input listener is normally done by the browser - so when you change the model directly you are forced to also trigger the event.

Comment: hi, this worked for textboxes but I tried same thing with hidden field but it did not work. So requirement is same but with hidden field.
Also what is input in .trigger('input')? I have read that we have to sepcify name of event to fire and input is not an event name.

Comment: .trigger('input') is an event name. For a hidden field you can try `$(elementId).triggerHandler("change");`

Comment: yes tried that but the value in scope was not updated. tried it like this: angular.element(hdnElement.selector).triggerHandler('change'); also hdnElement.trigger('change');